# how to access local.php file from controller in zf3

Tags: zend-framework, config, zf3

I am working with Zend-framework 3. I want to access the content of config files (local.php) in the controller. please explain. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found the simplest way to access any config file. Just in your Module.php pass  `$container->get('config')` as one of the argument to your controller's constructor and voila you can now access any property in the controller. That much simple. :-) Happy coding..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (it's not tested):

```
// config.php
return [
   'webhost'  => 'www.example.com',
   'database' => [
     'adapter' => 'pdo_mysql',
     'params'  => [
        'host'     => 'db.example.com',
        'username' => 'dbuser',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'dbname'   => 'mydatabase',
     ],
   ],
];
```

And in your controller:

```
// Consumes the configuration array
$config = new Zend\Config\Config(include 'config.php');

// Print a configuration datum (results in 'www.example.com')
echo $config->webhost;
```

Presume, you have this ZF3 package: zend-config
If you dont have, you have to include it via composer

```
composer require zendframework/zend-config
```